# List of minimal pairs in Turkish

Tags: resource-request, turkish, minimal-pairs

Is anyone aware of a resource (web-based or in print) providing a comprehensive list of minimal pairs in Turkish?

Answer (score 7):

There doesn't appear to be such a list, hence I made you one based on [this word list](http://zemberek.googlecode.com/files/full.txt.tr.tar.gz):

```
i o 
aç iç öç uç üç 
ad od öd 
af of öf uf 
ağ eğ iğ 
ah eh ıh oh 
ak ek ok 
al el il ol öl 
an en in on ön un ün 
ar er ör ur 
as es is ıs us üs 
aş eş iş üş 
at et it ot öt ut üt 
av ev iv ov öv 
ay ey oy uy 
az ez iz öz uz üz 
be de he le ne re ve ye 
bu hu mu su şu 
da fa ha la na ta ya 
em im om um 
hı mı 
ip öp 
ki mi pi si ti 
mü nü 
aç ad af ağ ah ak al an ar as aş at av ay az 
be bu 
da de do 
eğ eh ek el em en er es eş et ev ey ez 
ha he hı hu 
iç iğ il im in ip is iş it iv iz 
ıh ıs 
la le 
mi mı mu mü 
na ne nü 
öç öd öf öl ön öp ör öt öv öz 
od of oh ok ol om on ot ov oy 
si su 
ta ti 
uç uf um un ur us ut uy uz 
üç ün üs üş üt üz 
ya ye 
aba oba 
aça uça 
ada eda oda uda 
adi idi udi 
aha ıha oha 
ahi ehi 
ahı ıhı 
ahu ohu 
ait bit çit dit fit git kit mit yit 
aka ika oka 
aks iks 
ala ela ila ola ula 
ali eli ili pli 
alı ılı 
ama ima oma uma 
ana ona una 
ani eni ini 
ara ıra ora ura 
ark erk irk ırk örk ürk 
art ört 
arz ırz 
asa ısa usa 
asi esi isi 
ası ısı 
aşı ışı 
ast üst 
ata ita ota uta 
ate ete ite öte üte 
ati eti iti 
aut but dut fut gut kut put sut şut tut yut 
ava ova 
aya oya uya 
aza eza uza 
baç haç kaç maç saç taç zaç 
bağ cağ çağ dağ sağ yağ zağ 
bak çak fak gak hak kak lak pak sak şak tak yak 
bal çal dal fal hal kal lal mal nal pal sal şal tal yal 
bam cam çam dam fam gam ham kam lam nam sam tam yam zam 
ban can çan dan fan han kan lan nan san şan tan yan zan 
bap çap hap kap lap rap sap şap tap yap 
bar car çar dar far gar har kar nar sar tar var yar zar 
baş faş kaş maş şaş taş yaş 
bas has kas mas nas pas tas yas 
bat çat hat kat mat pat sat şat tat vat yat zat 
bav çav dav hav kav lav sav tav 
bay cay çay fay hay kay pay ray say tay vay yay 
baz caz daz faz gaz haz kaz naz saz şaz yaz 
bek çek dek fek kek pek sek şek tek yek 
bel çel del gel jel kel mel sel tel yel 
ben den fen gen hen len men nen ren sen şen ten ven yen zen 
beş deş keş leş peş şeş 
bet cet det jet ket met net ret set şet yet 
bey hey ley mey ney pey rey şey 
bez gez kez sez tez 
biç hiç piç 
bil çil dil fil kil mil pil sil zil 
bin cin din hin kin pin sin tin 
bip cip çip dip kip şip tip 
bir çir gir kir lir mir pir tir zir 
bis çis his mis pis sis 
biz çiz diz giz siz tiz 
boğ doğ loğ yoğ 
bok çok dok fok kok lok sok şok tok yok 
böl çöl döl göl höl 
bol dol fol gol hol kol rol sol tol yol 
bom dom kom rom som şom yom zom 
bön dön fön gön jön sön yön 
bor çor hor kor lor mor sor tor yor zor 
boş coş hoş koş loş 
bot kot not pot rot 
boy doy koy poy soy toy 
boz doz koz poz toz yoz 
bre ere öre üre 
bük dük tük yük 
bul çul dul ful jul kul pul tul 
bum hum kum mum şum yum zum 
bun dun hun sun şun tun yun 
bur dur kur nur sur tur vur 
buy duy huy 
büz cüz düz güz süz yüz 
buz kuz muz ruz tuz 
çeç geç meç seç 
cem dem gem hem kem lem nem rem sem tem vem yem zem 
cep hep kep lep tep 
cer çer der fer ger her ser şer ter ver yer zer 
cif lif sif şif 
çiğ fiğ 
çığ sığ tığ yığ 
cık çık gık hık mık sık şık tık vık yık 
cim çim kim mim nim pim sim tim 
çın kın sın tın 
cır dır fır gır hır kır mır pır sır vır yır 
çiş diş fiş hiş niş piş şiş 
cıs fıs kıs tıs 
çıt kıt pıt zıt 
çiy giy siy 
cız hız kız sız vız 
çök dök gök kök lök sök 
çöm göm 
cop hop kop lop pop rop sop top 
çöp löp 
çör gör kör sör tör 
çöz göz köz söz töz 
cup kup sup 
çüş düş 
def lef şef tef 
değ yeğ 
deh leh 
dev gev sev şev 
dik kik pik sik tik 
dış fış kış 
don fon kon son ton yon 
döv söv 
dua şua 
dün gün nün sün tün yün 
dür gür hür kür pür sür tür 
duş huş kuş muş tuş 
ece öce 
ede ide öde 
eğe iğe 
ege öge 
eke öke 
eki iki ski 
ele ile ole öle 
eme ime 
ene ine öne üne 
epe ipe öpe 
erg org 
eri gri iri 
ese ise 
eşe işe 
eşi işi 
eve ive öve 
eye iye üye 
eyi iyi 
eze ize öze üze 
fes kes pes ses 
fos pos sos tos 
gaf haf laf raf saf 
ged yed 
gıy kıy 
göç pöç 
göt höt 
göy köy 
gül kül tül zül 
güm nüm tüm 
güt jüt küt süt tüt 
hac sac 
had şad yad 
hah kah nah pah sah şah vah 
içe üçe 
ifa ofa ufa 
irs örs 
kıç sıç 
kıh mıh rıh zıh 
kıl yıl 
kıp şıp tıp zıp 
kof pof sof 
kös lös tös 
kov şov 
küf püf tüf 
küp lüp tüp 
kus pus sus 
küs püs süs 
odu udu 
ofu ufu 
olu ulu 
onu unu 
önü ünü 
örü ürü 
osu usu 
oyu uyu 
puf ruf yuf 
ruh şuh tuh yuh 
aba aça ada ağa aha aka ala ama ana ara asa aşa ata ava aya aza 
abi adi afi ahi ali ani asi ati 
abu agu ahu 
acı açı adı ağı ahı akı alı anı arı ası aşı atı avı ayı azı 
aft ait alt ant art ast aut 
alp arp 
ark ask aşk 
baç biç 
bağ boğ 
bak bek bok bük 
bal bel bil bol böl bul 
bam bom bum 
ban ben bin bön bun 
bap bip 
bar bir bor bur 
baş beş boş 
bas bis 
bat bet bit bot but 
bay bey boy buy 
baz bez biz boz buz büz 
çağ çiğ çığ 
çak çek çık çok çök 
çal çel çil çöl çul 
cam cem cim 
çam çim çöm 
can cin 
çan çın 
çap çip çöp 
car cer cır 
çar çer çir çor çör 
çat çit çıt 
çay çiy 
caz cız cüz 
cep cip cop cup 
çiş çüş 
çiz çöz 
dağ değ doğ düğ 
dal del dil dol döl dul 
dam dem dom 
dan den din don dön dun dün 
dar der dır dur dür 
dav dev döv 
daz diz doz düz 
dek dik dok dök dük 
deş diş dış döş duş düş 
det dit dut 
doy duy 
ebe ece ede efe ege eğe ehe eke ele eme ene epe ere ese eşe ete eve eye eze 
eda ela eza 
ehi eki eli eni eri esi eşi eti evi eyi 
fak fek fok 
fal fil fol ful 
fan fen fon fön 
far fer fır 
faş fiş fış 
fes fıs fos 
fit fut 
gak gık gök 
gam gem göm güm 
gar ger gir gır gör gür 
gaz gez giz göz güz 
geç göç güç 
gel gol göl gül 
gen gön gün 
git göt gut güt 
giy gıy göy 
haç hiç 
hak hık 
hal hol höl 
ham hem hım hum 
han hen hin hun 
hap hep hop 
har her hır hor hür 
has his 
hat höt 
hay hey huy 
haz hız 
hiş hoş huş 
içe ide iğe ile ime ine ipe ise işe ite ive iye ize 
içi idi iği iki ili imi ini ipi iri isi işi iti iyi izi 
ifa ika ila ima ita 
ıha ıra ısa 
ıhı ılı ısı ışı 
iks irs 
ilk irk 
jel jul 
jet jüt 
kaç kıç koç 
kah kıh 
kak kek kik kok kök 
kal kel kil kıl kol kul kül 
kam kem kim kom kum 
kan kin kın kon 
kap kep kip kıp kop kup küp 
kar kir kır kor kör kur kür 
kaş keş kış koş kuş 
kas kes kıs kös kus küs 
kat ket kit kıt kot kut küt 
kav kov 
kay kıy koy köy 
kaz kez kız koz köz kuz 
kof küf 
laf lef lif 
lak lok lök 
lam lem 
lan len 
lap lep lop löp lüp 
leş loş 
lir lor 
maç meç 
mal mel mil 
mas mis 
maş muş 
mat met mit 
mim mum 
mir mır mor 
nam nem nim nüm 
nan nen nün 
nar nur 
net not 
oba oda ofa oha oka ola oma ona ora ota ova oya 
öce öde öge öke öle öne öpe öre öte öve öze 
öcü ödü ölü önü örü özü 
odu ofu ohu oku olu omu onu osu otu oyu 
oje ole 
pak pek pik 
pal pil pul 
pas pes pis pos pus püs 
pat pıt pot put 
pay pey poy 
peş piş 
piç pöç 
pir pır pür 
pof pöf puf püf 
raf ruf 
rap rop 
ray rey 
rem rom 
ret rot 
rıh ruh 
saç seç sıç suç 
saf sif sof 
sağ sığ 
şah şuh 
sak sek sik sık sok sök 
şak şek şık şok 
sal sel sil sol 
sam sem sim som 
san sen sin sın son sön sun sün 
şan şen şun 
şap şip şıp 
sap sop sup 
sar ser sır sor sör sur sür 
şaş şeş şiş 
şat şet şut 
sat set sut süt 
sav sev söv 
say siy soy 
saz sez siz sız söz süz 
şef şif 
ses sis sos sus süs 
şev şov 
şom şum 
tak tek tik tık tok tük 
tal tel tol tul tül 
tam tem tim tüm 
tan ten tin tın ton tun tün 
tap tep tip tıp top tüp 
tar ter tir tor tör tur tür 
tas tıs tos tös 
taş tuş 
tat tut tüt 
tay toy tüy 
tef tüf 
tez tiz toz töz tuz 
tığ tuğ 
tuh tüh 
uca uça uda ufa ula uma una ura usa uta uya uza 
üçe üne üre üte üye üze 
ucu udu ufu ulu unu uru usu uyu uzu 
üçü ünü ürü üşü ütü 
var ver vır vur 
yad yed 
yağ yeğ yığ yoğ 
yak yek yık yok yük 
yal yel yıl yol 
yam yem yom yum 
yan yen yon yön yun yün 
yar yer yır yor 
yat yet yit yut 
yaz yoz yüz 
zam zem zom zum 
zan zen 
zar zer zir zor 
zat zıt 
zil zül 
aba abd abi abu 
aça açı 
ada adi adı 
afi aft 
ağa ağı 
aha ahi ahı ahu 
aka akı aks akü 
ala alg ali alı alo alp alt 
ana ani anı ant 
ara arı ark arp arş art arz 
asa asi ası ask ast 
aşa aşı aşk 
ata ate ati atı 
ava avı 
aya ayı ayn 
aza azı 
baç bağ bak bal bam ban bap bar bas baş bat bav bay baz 
bej bek bel ben beş bet bey bez 
biç bil bin bip bir bis bit biz 
boa boğ bok bol bom bor boş bot boy boz 
böl bön 
bük büz 
bul bum bun bur but buy buz 
çağ çak çal çam çan çap çar çat çav çay 
cağ cam can car cay caz 
çeç çek çel çer 
cem cep cer cet 
cif cim cin cip 
çığ çık çın çıt 
çiğ çil çim çip çir çis çiş çit çiy çiz 
cık cır cıs cız 
çök çöl çöm çöp çör çöz 
çok çor 
cop coş 
dağ dal dam dan dar dav daz 
def değ deh dek del dem den der deş det dev 
dik dil din dip diş dit diz 
dır dış 
doğ dok dol dom don doy doz 
dök döl dön döş döv 
dua dul dun duo dur duş dut duy 
düğ dük dün dür düş düz 
eda ede 
ege ego 
ehe ehi 
eke eki 
ela ele eli 
ene eni 
ere erg eri erk 
ese esi 
eşe eşi 
ete eti 
eve evi 
eye eyi 
eza eze 
fak fal fam fan far faş fay faz 
fek fen fer fes 
fiğ fil fiş fit 
fır fıs fış 
fob fok fol fon fos 
ful fut 
gaf gag gak gam gar gaz 
geç ged gel gem gen ger gev gez 
gık gır gıy 
gir git giy giz 
göç gök göl göm gön gör göt göy göz 
güç gül güm gün gür güt güz 
hac haç had haf hah hak hal ham han hap har has hat hav hay haz 
hem hen hep her hey 
hiç hin his hiş 
hık hım hır hız 
hol hop hor hoş 
höl höt 
hum hun huş huy 
içe içi 
ide idi 
iğe iği 
ıha ıhı 
ika iki iks 
ila ile ili ilk 
ima ime imi 
inç ine ini 
ipe ipi 
ıra ırk ırz 
iri irk irs 
ısa ısı 
ise isi 
işe işi 
ita ite iti 
iye iyi 
ize izi 
jel jet 
kaç kah kak kal kam kan kap kar kas kaş kat kav kay kaz 
kek kel kem kep kes keş ket kez 
kıç kıh kıl kın kıp kır kıs kış kıt kıy kız 
kik kil kim kin kip kir kit 
koç kod kof kok kol kom kon kop kor koş kot kov koy koz 
kök kör kös köy köz 
küf kül küp kür küs küt 
kul kum kup kur kus kuş kut kuz 
laf lak lal lam lan lap lav 
lef leh lem len lep leş ley 
lif lig lir 
loğ lok lop lor loş 
lök löp lös 
maç mai mal mas maş mat 
meç mel men met mey 
mıh mık mır 
mil mim mir mis mit 
mum muş muz 
nah nal nam nan nar nas naz 
nem nen net ney 
nim niş 
nüm nün 
öce öcü 
oda odu 
öde ödü 
ofa ofu 
oha ohm ohu 
oka oku 
ola ole olu 
ölç öle ölü 
oma omu 
ona ons onu 
öne önü 
ora org 
öre örf örk örs ört örü 
ota oto otu 
oya oyu 
öze özü 
pah pak pal pas pat pay 
pek pes peş pey 
piç pik pil pim pin pir pis piş 
pır pıt 
pöç pöf 
pof pop pos pot poy poz 
puf pul pus put 
püf pür püs 
raf rap ray 
rem ren ret rey 
rol rom rop rot 
ruf ruh ruj ruz 
sac saç saf sağ sah sak sal sam san sap sar sat sav say saz 
şad şah şak şal şan şap şaş şat şaz 
şeb şef şek şen şer şeş şet şev şey 
seç sek sel sem sen ser ses set sev sez 
sıç sığ sık sın sır sız 
sif sik sil sim sin sis siy siz 
şif şip şiş 
şık şıp 
sof sok sol som son sop sor sos soy 
şok şom şov 
sök sön sör söv söz 
şua şuh şum şun şut 
suç sun sup sur sus sut 
sün sür süs süt süz 
taç tak tal tam tan tap tar tas taş tat tav tay 
tef tek tel tem ten tep ter tez 
tığ tık tın tıp tıs 
tik tim tin tip tir tiz 
tok tol ton top tor tos toy toz 
tör tös töz 
tüf tüh tük tül tüm tün tüp tür tüt tüy 
tuğ tuh tul tun tur tuş tut tuz 
uca ucu 
üçe üçü 
uda udi udu 
ufa ufu 
ula ulu 
una unu 
üne ünü 
ura uru 
üre ürk ürü 
usa usu 
üte ütü 
uya uyu 
uza uzu 
vah var vat vay 
vem ven ver 
vık vır vız 
yad yağ yak yal yam yan yap yar yas yaş yat yay yaz 
yed yeğ yek yel yem yen yer yet 
yığ yık yıl yır 
yit yiv 
yoğ yok yol yom yon yor yoz 
yuf yuh yum yun yut 
yük yün yüz 
zaç zağ zam zan zar zat 
zem zen zer 
zıh zıp zıt 
zil zir 
zom zor
```

Those are only the minimal pairs in words of at most three letters. There are quite a few with four letters and more, but the post would then exceed the maximum length, so I left them out.

In case anyone needs the script I used to make this (e.g. to get the minimal pairs for longer words or to adapt it to a word list of another language):

```
#!/bin/bash

# word list used (assumed to be unpacked in current directory):
# http://zemberek.googlecode.com/files/full.txt.tr.tar.gz

# remove those numbers after the words that file has.
sed 's/ [0-9]*$//' -i~ full.txt.tr

# split the word list into files with equal lengths.
# e.g. 07.tmp will contain 7-letter-words.
x=1;
s='.';
# wc -L full.txt.tr says there are words at most 33 characters long.
while [ $x -le 33 ]; do
    z=$x;
    if [ $x -lt 10 ]; then
        z=0$x;
    fi;
    grep '^'$s'$' full.txt.tr > $z.txt;s="$s."; x=$(($x+1));
done

# now for each word find the minimal pairs.
i=1;
unsorted=`mktemp`;
while [ $i -lt 34 ]; do
    echo "Examining words of length: $i";
    file=$i;
    if [ $i -lt 10 ]; then
        file=0$i;
    fi;
    j=1;
    s='';
    # in each position within the word there may occur a minimal pair.
    while [ $j -le $i ]; do
        outfile=`mktemp`;
        for word in `cat $file.txt`; do
            tmpfile=`mktemp`;
            echo $word > $tmpfile;
            grep "`echo $word | sed 's/^\('$s'\)./\1./;'`" $file.txt | grep -v "$word" >> $tmpfile;
            # same group of minimal pairs appears multiple times,
            # so sort each group so duplicates can be found.
            for x in `sort $tmpfile`; do echo -n "$x " >> $outfile; done
            echo "" >> $outfile;
            rm $tmpfile;
        done;
        # remove repetitions of same line of minimal pairs
        # and lines with only one word (i.e. without minimal pairs).
        sort -u $outfile | sed '/^[^ ]* $/d' >> $unsorted;
        rm $outfile;
        s=$s'.';
        j=$(($j+1));
    done;
    i=$(($i+1));
done
sort -u $unsorted > result.txt
rm $unsorted;
rm *.tmp;
```

Note that this script assumes that in the transcription one character corresponds to one phoneme. If that doesn't apply then you need to write your own, I was too lazy to account for that. For the same reason this script runs extremely slow.

Comment: This answer is good, because although it doesn't give the "comprehensive list of minimal pairs" which OP asked for (that would be impossible!) You've provided OP with the tool to get nearly that if he/she/ze chooses. Plus, I think this answer applies not only to Turkish, but to any transcription you feed into that script, is that right?

Comment: Would it also work for letters with combining diacritics (like  ̄)? I've had problems with that before.