# minimal pairs for Portuguese

Tags: pronunciation, resource-request, portuguese, minimal-pairs

Does anyone know of a list of minimal pairs for pronunciation, preferably with audio files?
So far the best I have found https://european-portuguese.info/minimalpairs but this is specific to European. Most searches return ESL resources for Portuguese speakers.

Comment: Would be very interesting if there is a general and/or programmatic way of finding minimal pairs.

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer There is, even here on Linguistics.SE. I'll see if I can find it and mark this as a dupe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of minimal pairs in Turkish](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/11090/list-of-minimal-pairs-in-turkish)

Comment: @wilson: I don't see a generic answer to find minimal pairs for arbitrary languages in the question you quote, only a Turkish specific answer is given there.

Comment: @jknappen From what I can see, that script will return the minimal pairs in any corpus you give it, depending on the transcription's grapheme to phoneme relationship.

Comment: @wilson The script only works for languages with near-phonemic orthography.

Comment: @jknappen If that's not the case for Portuguese, there may be a way to mechanically convert a word to something like IPA or whatever. I don't know enough to say

Comment: Thanks, this is a good idea. I think with the right dataset the results could be very useful.

Comment: Are you looking for minimal pairs in any specific dialect?